# Delete last printed element from console

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

**QUESTION**   Given two unsorted arrays A of size N and B of size M of distinct elements, the task is to find all pairs from both arrays whose sum is equal to X.

```
 **INPUT**
    1
    5 5 9
    1 2 4 5 7
    5 6 3 4 8


**EXPECTED OUTPUT** 1 8, 4 5, 5 4

**MY OUTPUT**   1 8, 4 5, 5 4,
```

**MY CODE**

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
void Pair(int *a, int*b, int n, int m, int sum) {
    map<int, int>mp;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        int x = a[i];
        for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
            if ((sum - x) == b[i])
                mp[x] = b[i];
        }
    }

    for (auto x : mp) {
        cout << x.first << " " << x.second << ",";
         
    }
  
}
int main() {

    int  test ;
    cin >> test;
    for (int i = 0; i < test; i++) {
        int  a[1000000];
        int  b[1000000];
        int  n, m, sum;
        cin >> n >> m >> sum;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            cin >> a[i];
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
            cin >> b[i];
        }
        Pair(a, b, n, m, sum); 
       
        cout << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I have already tried /b/b but it does not works here I don't know why please help me print the correct output and also suggest me a better way of doing it

I have to remove the last comma printed.

Comment: So you could reduce your question to: how can I avoid printing the last comma in the following loop? `for (auto x : mp) { cout << x.first << " " << x.second << ","; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this:

```cpp
    for (auto x : mp) {
        cout << x.first << " " << x.second << ",";
         
    }
```

with:

```cpp
    auto it = mp.begin();
    auto end = mp.end();
    for (; it != end; ++it) {
        cout << (*it).first << ' ' << (*it).second;
        if ( std::next(it, 1) != end) { // check if next is end
            cout << ", "; //if not, print a comma
        }
    }
```

---

**Side note:** [Don't include `<bits/stdc++>`](https://stackoverflow.com/Questions/31816095/Why-Should-I-Not-Include-Bits-Stdc-H.)

Comment: thanks . But what is with <bits/stdc++.h> can you tell me what is wrong in that

Comment: Read the link I put in, it explains it well. But to put it simply, just include the headers you need i.e: `<map>, <iostream>`

Answer (score 2):

```
bool first = true;
for (auto x : mp)
{
    if (!first)
    {
        cout << ", ";
    }
    cout << x.first << " " << x.second;
    first = false;
}
```